# Bigquery insert - multiple rows at a time from python dict

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I insert a python dictionary with 5k rows into bigquery? I used the documentation at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/streaming.py but I am able only to insert 1 row at a time.

How can insert all the 5k rows in the dictionary at a time? If I use a pandas dataframe to insert, I get the error `NotImplementedError: Google's libraries do not support Python 3 yet`.

Here's my code:

```py
for rows in dict1:
    insert_all_data = {
                       'rows': [{'json' : rows}]
                       }
    bigquery_service.tabledata().insertAll(projectId='na-sem',datasetId='Rules',tableId='my_table',body=insert_all_data).execute(num_retries=2)
```

Pandas data frame method

```
bigquery_results_df.to_gbq('samples.test', project_id='sample', chunksize=10000, verbose=True, reauth=False)
```

That returns the error:

> NotImplementedError: Google's libraries do not support Python 3 yet.

Comment: You should be able to stream multiple rows to BigQuery, but maybe 5k on one call might be too much. On the Python 3 error - did you try with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

In our self-serve environment for non-tech staff we address this mostly in one of two below ways. Of course - how relevant it is for you case - depends :)

1. If dictionary is static and available in advance we are uploading it to storage and then loading to bigquery - that is classic scenario
2. If dictionary is dynamic and actually being created on fly within app (self-serve env) - we are building "fake" query consisting of as many select statement with dictioinary data as bigquery size allows and than execute query job with destination table of choice

So like below simplified:

```
SELECT id, itemA, itemB FROM
  (SELECT 1 as id, 'a1' as itemA, 'b1' as itemB),
  (SELECT 2 as id, 'a2' as itemA, 'b2' as itemB),
  (SELECT 3 as id, 'a3' as itemA, 'b3' as itemB)
```